# Comparing values from two different tables while inserting into another 'middle table'

Tags: mysql

So I have two tables

Club - ID_Club, Name, Nationality

and

League - ID_league, Name, Nationality

between them is a middle table "PLAY AT"
which connects ID of a club with League ID -> specifies in which league the club will play. Is there any way to check if the Club's Nationality equals the Leagues nationality while inserting the club into league through that middle table? I want to secure that for example Spanish Club can play only in spanish league. Thank you for aswers.

Comment: Yes, but what have you tried?

Comment: Slightly Off topic, but are you sure this is a good idea to model this relation like so? What if you consider European Champions League and Real Madrid. The Nationality of Champions League does not seem to fit your model. Real Madrid is Spanish, Bayern Munich is German and both play the Champions League.

Comment: Nothing really, I don't even know how to start, I understand triggers should be used to deal with this but how i don't know, I would like to give you more details, but as i said i am not really  good at this.

Comment: Worse example in Basketball: VTB United League is at the same time the highest Russian basketball league and at the same time in this league play other Nations teams from Belarus, Finland, Estonia etc. A better way of modeling this would modeling the governing bodies of the leagues, i.e. the sport associations and their hierarchy.

Comment: yea, i ruled the international competitions out. Have this as a end of a semestr work and it is not required to be as much detailed as irl i guess.

Answer (score 0):

> Is there any way to check if the Club's Nationality equals the Leagues
>   nationality

Yes, do a simple `INNER JOIN` between the tables like

```
select c.ID_Club, 
c.Name, 
c.Nationality,
l.ID_league, 
l.Name
from club c join league l on c.Nationality = l.Nationality;
```

(OR) Using `WHERE EXISTS`

```
select c.ID_Club, 
c.Name, 
c.Nationality
from club c 
where exists(select 1 from league where c.Nationality = Nationality);
```